# Alternative to fetchall (PDO)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is alternative to `fetchall` for real time loop?

Consider this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM record WHERE status = 0");
$query->execute();
$Record = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($Record as $row) {
 echo $row['name'];
 sleep(5)
}
```

While its looping and `echo`'ing, I updated `status = 1` from the console but it will still show the record which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a simple `fetch()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM record WHERE status = 0");
$query->execute();

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 echo $row['name'];
 sleep(5)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The results of the query are calculated once, when you run the query. If you need to get all *new* results with `status = 0`, you'll need to rerun the query.